# Is it possible to create a pointer to a class in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

How can I create a pointer to a class. I assume, that classes exists somewhere in  RAM, so, is it possible to get a pointer to it?
I don't mean a pointer to an object, I mean a pointer to the class itself (like a function pointer).

Comment: " pointers to classes" or "classes are objects too" is an idea in some other languages to manipulate types at runtime. In C++, type manipulation is done via templates at compile time, e.g. `std::array<int.10>` to make an array out of integers.

Comment: To me, this sounds like an [X/Y Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: @drescherjm: It might make sense. Think about reflection, or simply some meta programmation. `std::is_same` would simply be `==` from those OP expected variables.

Comment: class is abstract schematics for compiler, used at compile time only, so it knows how to construct new instance, and how to manipulate with instance (instance is physically in memory). That knowledge is "imprinted" into produced machine code, which implements methods working with instances (like constructor/destructor and other class methods). After compilation that abstract knowledge is not needed any more and is thrown away, only the machine code implementing all of that behaviour is stored in the executable. I.e. your assumptions about class being in ram at run-time is wrong. It's not there

Comment: This is a question that makes perfect sense (and has a solution) in Java, C# and other languages that have reflection. But this is C++, and here classes cease to exist during compilation, so the answer is just a firm: No.

Comment: If you want to "put some data into class", you can use static class variables, and obtain particular pointer to each of them, but each of that is just that particular variable and nothing more, doesn't have any kind of "envelope" acting as "class", from machine code point of view it is just one big ball of "global"-like variables (all the static variables from all classes together somewhere in the "data" section of memory).

Comment: @dave It's not, at the point were I asked this question, I already solved the problem in another way (that seems to be the best solution for me, even if class-pointers existed). I just asked, because I was interested, if it could work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I assume, that classes exist somewhere in the Ram

Classes do not exist at run-time, so you cannot take a pointer to a class.

Only objects exist at run-time.

Comment: Just to prevent confusion from visitors from other programming languages: Yes, some other languages include reflection which allows one to inspect types at runtime, and "get a pointer to the class" (example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8). However, C++ does not include reflection, and the above is the correct answer for the C++ language.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. C++ has three types of pointers:

1. Pointers to objects
2. Pointers to functions
3. Pointers to class members.

Classes are none of the above.